# Designing Rack awareness feature?

Tags: hadoop

I would like to understand the design of rack awareness fearture in products like kafka, hadoop and others. How was rack awareness built in these systems, how does the hadoop know which server is in which Rack? I would like build the same for my service which would map servers to the rack, show which servers are sitting in which Rack?

One way I was thinking is using the rack TOR switch to which server is connected to, in this way service will know which server is sitting in which rack, I am not sure if there is any other way?

Answer (score 0):

> how does the hadoop know which server is in which Rack?

It doesn't. The operator does. The rack must be manually defined in the config file. When using a cloud service, such as AWS EMR, however, since you have no direct control over physical machines and literal server racks in the datacenter, further configuration is required. Regions are often used instead, though AWS has a feature called "placement groups".

Otherwise, use S3, GCP, Azure Blob storage which are all HDFS compatible.

"Awareness" in terms of Hadoop HDFS is related to limiting of network traffic. If you have 3 replicas of any block/file segment, then you want one disk local copy (same OS, often different volume), one rack local copy (managed by a different OS volume, but on the same network link), then a remote copy, on a different rack, but still same LAN network for fast transfers.

For Kafka, it's used for the clients that would be running in the same datacenter, in order to coordinate with the brokers on which replicas should be prioritized by a consumer to poll, since clients must communicate with leader partition brokers first. If your clients are running in other regions, or you're consuming from a cloud Kafka service on your local machine, there's no benefits of rack awareness from the client perspective, and Kafka doesn't use the same algorithm as Hadoop for distributing replicas.

Comment: *This setting doesn't really make sense in cloud services*  Though AWS has notion of [placement-groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html) and it is supported by [EMR for example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-ha-placementgroup.html)

Comment: Fair, though that's a cluster design feature, not application config. I'll rephrase the post